# How to expand LIs to full width of DIV

Tags: html, css

this is my html code:

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>My blah</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor amet</li>
  <li>photogallery</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#menu li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

`#menu` is in `#header-wrap` which is 800px wide. I want to expand text inside UL to be same size as #menu which is 800px. I can't do it with `margin-left` and `margin-right` because it leaves blank spaces or it move `li` on another line which I don't want.

So is there any element that I can add into the CSS and it will expand text to 800px?

[image]

I can't use `word-spacing` because some things in `li`s has more than one word.

Comment: why dont use simple increase the width of your div, because i think the div with id '#menu' is being restricted from getting expanded to its parent`s size

Comment: Is a number of LI's predefined?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by predefined but we will have 7 LI's which won't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've specified the `display` property to be `inline`. Inline elements will collapse to their content's width.

If you want it to have the width set change `display` to either `block` or `inline-block`.

```
#menu li {
 display: inline-block; /*compensate for spaces in the source if using this*/
 width: 20%; /* for 5 li's (100%/5)*/
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; /* optional */
 list-style-type: none;
}



#menu li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 20%; /* for 5 li's (100%/5)*/
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center; /* optional */
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

EDIT: For 7 LI's change the width percentage to 14.25%. This will give you a little bit of space on the right side which can be adjusted by center-aligning the list container.

EDIT: As FAngel pointed out, `inline-block` elements have an annoying habit of letting formatting spaces show through, so that `block` + `float` approach is more desirable.

Comment: One note: inline block will not work there. Spaces (or line endings) after li's will add additional space after each li and move 5th element on a new line (like here http://jsfiddle.net/htkhH/). Possible fix for that situation: remove LI closing tags like here http://jsfiddle.net/htkhH/1/

Comment: @FAngel Right you are! Linking an article for reference: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I used your code but it doesn't work as expected. :/ http://jsfiddle.net/Zvp8e/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @Kyrbi I've updated your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Zvp8e/2/ Please read FAngel's comment on my post and also my last edit.

Answer (score 5):

This SO post should be useful for what you need

[CSS - horizonal navigation list items to fill all available spce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921960/css-horizonal-navigation-list-items-to-fill-all-available-spce)

Your css might be like this:

```
 #menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #menu li {
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, another way to do it without `display: table` is to unfloat the final `<li>` and give it `overflow: hidden;`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .wrapper {width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;}

        ul {list-style: none; margin:0; padding:0;}

        ul li {float: left;}

        ul li.last {float: none; overflow: hidden;}

        li a {
            color: #222;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            background: #e7e7e7;
            padding: 0 62px;
        }

        li.last a {padding: 0; text-align: center;}

        li a:hover, li a:focus {background: #222; color: #fff;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sit</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">amet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, instead of the `class="last"`, `li:last-child` could be used, but the class makes it slightly more backwards compatible. It does rely on a fixed-width design, though, which is a bit out of date these days.